# Заполнение структуры на сайте посредством ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На сайте есть структура (table), в которой находятся ордера.

Каждый пользователь может добавлять свой ордер после заполнения необходимых полей и нажатия кнопки "добавить" после необходимые данные подгружаются в БД в общую таблицу и оттуда уже попадают на страницу.

Как сделать так, чтобы страница постоянно подгружала все возможные ордера из БД, а не только те, которые добавил конкретный пользователь?

Comment: Знает кто как сделать?

Comment: На такой общий вопрос могу дать общий ответ: получение актуальных данных с сервера можно реализовать веб-сокетами или самодудосом через ajax (очень часто отправлять ajax запросы на сервер с проверкой на появление новых данных).

Comment: И жмите зелёную галку у верных ответов на ваши вопросы, будьте любезны.

Comment: Под "постоянно подгружала" вы имеете в виду чтобы можно было наблюдать в реальном времени их появление в общей таблице? А насчет  "не только те, которые добавил конкретный пользователь" - если у вас в таблице отображаются только записи конкретного пользователя, а нужно показывать все,то просто модифицируйте запрос.. Если я кончено все так понял